# Unsuccessful updates due to misconfigured sources

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, update-manager

I deleted a file from `/etc/apt/` but don't remember what I deleted.

When I try to update using `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error:

```
Ign:1 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                    
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                             
Ign:3 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease                                                     
Ign:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dartsim/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                    
Ign:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
0% [Working]                                                                                                                                 
Get:6 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                   
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                    
Ign:3 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease                                                     
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                   
Hit:8 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release                                                       
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                               
Get:11 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                               
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ts.sch.gr/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                 
Ign:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                              
Ign:11 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                          
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dartsim/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:1 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Get:14 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [94.8 kB]
Get:15 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [257 kB]                  
Get:16 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                                  
Ign:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:11 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                    
Get:17 http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.7 kB]
Err:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is what I have in `/etc/apt/`:

```
apt.conf.d  auth.conf.d  keyrings  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list.d  trusted.gpg.d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit the win-key (= Super-key) and begin to type `software & updates`
   quite soon you will see a pinkish icon; click on it.
2. In the window that appears; click `Other software` (tab at top)
3. find `ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/` (or something similar to it) and remove the tick to the left of it. It should be a single line.
4. Do `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` **or** Hit the Super key again, begin to type `update` and click on `Update softw...` when it appears.

*Note: this is for 20.04 / focal fossa, might be slightly different for 22.04 / jammy jellyfish*